# How to assign Spring Data LDAP repository to a specific connection (LDAPTemplate)?

Tags: java, ldap, spring-data, spring-ldap

I have a Spring Data LDAP repository like this:

```
package x.y.z.repository;

import org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import x.y.z.domain.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends LdapRepository<User>{
    User findByUserId(String userId);
}
```

Unfortunately I have more than one LDAP connection in the spring context. How can I define which `LDAPTemplate` belongs to which `Repository`? I have not found anything in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/ldap/docs/current/reference/html/index.html).

Comment: Hmm. ldap-template-ref is mentioned, however I cannot really find where it is to be defined. It seems to be an XML Config entry. Is it somehow possible with Java config?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out. In [EnableLdapRepositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/ldap/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/ldap/repository/config/EnableLdapRepositories.html) annotation it is possible to define the [template reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/ldap/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/ldap/repository/config/EnableLdapRepositories.html#ldapTemplateRef--).